# Is it possible to automatically return to my app after setting a social account for Social.framework?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, social-framework

In my app I'm using the Social framework to share status updates on Facebook and Twitter through an SLComposeViewController.

If the user doesn't have an account set up, he receives an alert that lets him go to the settings page.

Is there a way to automatically return to my app after setting up the account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put: no.

There is no call of action to navigate the user from settings to your app. You have to have faith the user will navigate to your app